# Create java script array dynamically whose name is in java script string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a collection of arrays which are generated dynamically. What I am trying to do is to implement an AutoComplete functionality. I want to use those arrays in click event handler, by getting name dynamically and assigning that to local array. But that is not working (I'm not sure abt my code). Is there any way to achieve that?

Here is my code which I believe should work (which does not work):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var ga_input1 = new Array('India','Russia','Norway');
    var ga_input2 = new Array('Delhi','Mumbai','Hyderabad');
</script>
<body>
    Countries: <input id="input1"  type="text"/>
    Cities: <input id="input2"  type="text"/>

    <script>
        var arrayTmp = new Array();
        $('input').keydown(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            arrayTmp = "ga_"+id; // What I believe here is the values of ga_input1/ga_input2 are assigned to array 'arrayTmp' 
            //alert(arrayTmp[0]);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All global variables are members of the window object, so:

```
arrayTmp = window["ga_"+id];
```

But I'd personally put the data in an object like this:

```
data = {
    'input1': ['India','Russia','Norway'],
    'input2': ['Delhi','Mumbai','Hyderabad']
};
...
arrayTmp = data[id];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put that arrays in a "Map" and later fetch them from it easily.

Here's how it's done:

```
var countryMap = {};
countryMap["Europe"] = ['Russia', 'England', 'Norway'];
countryMap["America"] = ['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico'];

....

var arrayTmp = countryMap["America"];
alert(arrayTmp[0]); //USA
alert(arrayTmp[1]); //Canada
alert(arrayTmp[2]); //Mexico
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have in `arrayTmp` is just a string `"ga_input1"`. Instead, try `eval("arrayTmp=ga_"+id);`.

Answer (score 0):

eval('var arrayTmp = ga_' + id);
alert(arrayTmp[0]);